# Parse FB SDK Login Application Transport Security errors on device but not on simulator XCode 7.1 Swift IOS 9 FBSDK 4.7

Tags: xcode, facebook, swift, parse-platform, ios9

Although I have seen similar questions posted here, I have not been able to resolve my issue via plist settings.  Any other ideas?  Here is where I am:

- Adding FB Login to a simple IOS app using the Parse framework
- All versions are up-to-date as of today.  XCode 7.1, IOS 9, Parse latest, FB SDK latest (4.7)
- I have added the specified IOS 9 settings for the FB SDK in my plist.  I even combined the lists to include the extra setting required for FB SDK 4.7.

The mystery:

- last night I could not get this to run on my simulator, but after
  re-adding the plist settings and re-importing all the libraries,  I
  finally got the FB login screens to show up on the iphone 6 (has been
  upgraded to IOS 9).  I couldn't get it to run on the simulator but i
  left it at that.
- now today i tried it on the iphone again and i keep getting the ATS-looking errors.
- On the iphone the error is:

  Cannot Verify Server Identity.  The identity of "m.facebook.com" cannot be verified by Safari.  Review the certificate details to continue.
- In the XCode console the error is:

  FBSDKLog: WARNING: FBSDK secure network request failed. Please verify you have configured your app for Application Transport Security compatibility described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

It seems to me that the plist fix is allowing the FB Login to work in my simulator, but why wouldn't it also work on the iphone?  Could this have anything to do with Parse?  Below is my login code:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBAction func FBLoginButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Set permissions required from the facebook user account
    var permissionsArray : [String]?
    permissionsArray = ["user_about_me"]
   var userBlock : PFUserResultBlock?

        // Login PFUser using Facebook
```

PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissionsArray, block: userBlock)

```
 PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissionsArray) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
            } else {
                print("User logged in through Facebook!")
            }
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.tableViewSegue, sender: nil)

        } else {
            print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
        if let e = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    print(userBlock.debugDescription)
}
```

[picture of plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH3MG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the mystery has been solved.  Parents of teens may be able to relate.

It turns out that last night when the login was working on my teen's iphone, it was set to use mobile data ON PURPOSE to bypass the content filtering settings on our network!  The reason I didn't realize this today was because the FB app seemed to be working on the iphone (upon later scrutiny I see that there was just some cached content), and my mac is set to bypass the content filtering.  So this is why it worked on the simulator but not on the iphone (when the iphone was set to use wifi and not mobile data).

So the FB error was a red herring.  I just wasn't looking down that path...